# read large sas file into chunks

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, sas, chunks

I encounter an Error when iterating chunks,

```
compustat = pd.read_sas("F:\\COMPUSTAT_annually.sas7bdat",
                    encoding='ISO-8859-1',
                    chunksize=1500)

dfs = []
i = 0
for chunk in compustat:
    dfs.append(chunk)

    
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

when i == 262,
it says:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sas\sas7bdat.py in
> _read_next_page(self)
> 738                 f"{len(self._cached_page):d} of {self._page_length:d} bytes)"
> 739             )
> --> 740             raise ValueError(msg)
> 741
> 742         self._read_page_header()
>
> ValueError: failed to read complete page from file (read 65536 of
> 131072 bytes) Exception ignored in:
> 'pandas.io.sas._sas.Parser.read_next_page' Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sas\sas7bdat.py", line 740,
> in _read_next_page
> raise ValueError(msg) ValueError: failed to read complete page from file (read 65536 of 131072 bytes)

I searched but saw no answers to this...
not sure if it has anything to do with the sas reading.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is not with the SAS dataset?  Can you read the dataset using SAS?

Comment: thanks, you saved my day ! It turned out that the compressor did something wrong.